# Calling a string / object to a adodb connection

Tags: html, vbscript, adodb

Hi all im having issues with this section of script;

```
linkString = "<a href=""#"" onclick=""TINY.box.show({iframe:'nodes/"& txtOpen.value &"',boxid:'frameless',width:750,height:450,fixed:false,maskopacity:0})"">Info</a> "

    SQL_query ="INSERT INTO search (Title,Program,Open) VALUES ('"& txtTitle.value &"','"& txtProgram.value &"','"& linkString.value &"')"
```

I basically need the code to input the "linkString" value into the section of my SQL Query however any way I try I recieve either object errors or string errors if I attempt to set the value?

Thanks, 
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`linkString` is a string, not an object. So there is no `linkString.value` to concatenate. Just use plain `linkString`.

**Update wrt comments:**

Assuming the objects and their properties are decent, your concatenations - though disgusting - are correct. Evidence:

```
txtTitle_value = "AAA"
txtProgram_value = "BBB"
linkString = "CCC"
txtOpen_value = "111"
linkString = "<a href=""#"" onclick=""TINY.box.show({iframe:'nodes/"& txtOpen_value &"',boxid:'frameless',width:750,height:450,fixed:false,maskopacity:0})"">Info</a>"
WScript.Echo linkString
SQL_query ="INSERT INTO search (Title,Program,Open) VALUES ('"& txtTitle_value &"','"& txtProgram_value &"','"& linkString &"')"
WScript.Echo SQL_query
```

output:

```
cscript 26403056.vbs
<a href="#" onclick="TINY.box.show({iframe:'nodes/111',boxid:'frameless',width:750,height:450,fixed:false,mask
opacity:0})">Info</a>
INSERT INTO search (Title,Program,Open) VALUES ('AAA','BBB','<a href="#" onclick="TINY.box.show({iframe:'nodes
/111',boxid:'frameless',width:750,height:450,fixed:false,maskopacity:0})">Info</a>')
```

If you get "missing operator" errors you removed those operators yourself.

**Update wrt comments II:**

If you get an SQL error, escape the single quotes in `linkString`; check your SQL docs to learn how ('', \', ...).

Comment: I have tried that the only problem is then it causes an Syntax Error ( missing opperator ) ?

Comment: I believe this is being caused by having the HTML code input as a string ? @ekkehard.Horner

Comment: The '"& txtOpen.value &"' section. This gets information from an input tag in HTML

Comment: I've marked the answer as correct as the question itself has been answered for the code however the error seems to be coming from the execution of the SQL_Query itself with my connection.

Comment: I've marked the answer as correct as the question itself has been answered for the code however the error seems to be coming from the execution of the SQL_Query itself with my connection.oConn.Execute(SQL_Query) It works in 3 other places I use to call it however it Must be causing the issue. But thanks anwyays @ekkehard.Horner